# Circular reference detected on TYPO3 11 backend login page

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I have a weird error when trying to call the TYPO3 11 backend login page.

I updated from TYPO3 10 and can't login anymore.

I already removed all of my custom extensions, but the error persists and I can't make out where it comes from or why.

It seems to crash when reaching the first `f:form.hidden` field of the default login Fluid template.

As this is an obvious issue that probably would have got caught by core devs, I am pretty sure that this is correlated to a configuration of my instance, but as I said, this is to weird of an issue for me and I have no idea where to dig for the issue.

This is error message:
[image]

I can provide the whole stacktrace if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the source of this issue.
I had the following configuration automatically generated in my `LocalConfiguration.php`.

```
'SC_OPTIONS' => [
    'GLOBAL' => [
        'softRefParser' => [
            'email' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Database\\SoftReferenceIndex',
            'ext_fileref' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Database\\SoftReferenceIndex',
            'notify' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Database\\SoftReferenceIndex',
            'substitute' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Database\\SoftReferenceIndex',
            'typolink' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Database\\SoftReferenceIndex',
            'typolink_tag' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Database\\SoftReferenceIndex',
            'url' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Database\\SoftReferenceIndex',
        ],
    ],
...
```

This caused the above error message. After removing this part from my configuration, the system lets me login and works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your .htaccess file with the new rules for the TYPO3 backend? You can find a sample file in the the Resources folder of install tool extension: `typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess`

And I assume that you cleared all caches in the install tool and did a `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: I did clear caches and composer autoload. I do not run apache. I have a combination of nginx with php-fpm in docker.